# Differences between MVC routing and SPA routing ?

Tags: javascript, meteor, model-view-controller, reactjs, single-page-application

I know how a **MVC** application handles routing,

---

1. (/foo/bar get) *request hits the server*
2. route /foo/bar with get method is found or not found, if found route handles the request by calling a method which serves a view page with corresponding data filled up.
3. client gets a html document with many links to other pages.
4. Another link is another procedure just like this one.

---

However, I have been learning react+meteor pack, which is a SPA (single page application) without ssr(server-side rendering). The most critical part that gets me confused is routing.Let's say I have 3 different routes for my SPA. (/), (/route2), (/route3)

1. (/route2) request hits the server. What does the server serve ? The whole application code with (/route2) active or what ?
2. Let s say we are on (/) route and clicked (/route2) route. So what s happening now ? Does react empty the #mainDıv and put related component instead, from where, the bundle.js which already contains all of the views' html as components ?
3. Is there a way to send only requested page's html and js, and after showing the content, getting other pages' html and js in the background, without client even feels. So that when another route is hit, only data will be on the wire.
4. Finally , only sending the related page's html - css - js  when requested,I don t don't know if such a technique exists, seems to lack the SPA experience, but I am not sure If it would lack SPA expereince. It would be great to explain how to approach this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a SPA you typically (read: virtually always) configure your server to serve the same bootstrap HTML/Javascript *regardless of which URL has been requested*. A request for `/route2` will get the same HTML response as a request for `/` or any other URL (unless you have specific exceptions for specific reasons). The SPA always starts with the same bootstrap code and examines the current browser's URL, then dynamically loads content as needed. How exactly that content is loaded and when it is loaded depends on the specific framework/code/circumstances/configuration, but yes, ultimately the contents of the DOM are dynamically being replaced by Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation which answers my first question perfectly. So my other questions are adressing the same issue, is there a way to send views partially? As you say, if the server has one entry point and one bootstrapp, how can this even be possible ? I have heard about webpack solution but my mind doesn t get how that can be solved with webpack? Only a  serverside solution is acceptable, when I think as you just answered. Bla bla. I am so confused.

Comment: As a corollary of my explanation... no, you don't typically send "partial views" to the initial request. You can and should break your SPA view templates into separate files which are loaded from the server as needed; each of these templates would be a "partial view". What exactly Meteor does I don't know, never used it.